# how to find memory leaks in java based web application using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am new to jmeter. We have developed a java based web application using spring framework. We want to know whether we can find memory leaks using jmeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a JMeter script for a few hours to create the load together with an Application Performance Monitoring solution like New Relic to look for memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter is not primary designated to find memory leaks. In few words the main rule of JMeter is request URLs so many times as you required and evaluate results you get back. That explanation is a bit simply and JMeter is really more complex then just this case. However if you guess you've a memory leak in your application, it can be useful in some cases to use JMeter just for to generate many request. However finding memory leaks IS NOT JMeter functionality. You have to monitor you application with some other tools (e.g. jmap, jvisualvm, etc.) and use JMeter just for to generate required specific requests.